# Retrieve MD5 from remote host

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, md5

My goal is to make a script which builds a packages (`.tar` files) on local machine, upload them to remote hosts and check MD5 hash sum.

How I would do it:

```
LOCALHASH=`md5sum package.tar | awk '{print $1}'`
scp package.tar user@host:/opt/package.tar # actually I should use 'expect' here

REMOTEHASH=`ssh user@host "md5sum /opt/package" | awk '{print $1}'`

# check REMOTEHASH == LOCALHASH and so on
```

The questions:

1. I don't want to deal with `expect`. I used it and I have a feeling that it betrays me.
2. Actually it's regular deploy problem. How did you solve this?

**P.S.** Actually I have a project with several packages after compiling. When the packages are built I want to get git revision number, time, version of compilers and `md5sum` of each package. Then the deploy script uploads the packages and check `md5sum`. Why did I say this? Because I can't create a common file with MD5 sums, upload this and just run md5 check command.

Comment: What's wrong with your solution?

Comment: it is probably worth learning how to use a package management system like debtools or rpm

Answer (score 2):

What I would do in this case :

```
LOCALHASH=$(md5sum package.tar | awk '{print $1}')
scp package.tar user@host:/opt/package.tar

REMOTEHASH=$(
ssh du@mir.afsoft.org <<'EOF'
md5sum /opt/package.tar | awk '{print $1}'
EOF
)

if [[ $LOCALHASH == $REMOTEHASH ]]; then
    ###
else
    ###
fi
```